# Real banner doesn't appear, just test ads. What's wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads, banner-ads

I Added Admob ads to my Unity game. Test ads work perfectly, but when I change to real ads none of these appear.
I've just started working with admob. I added banner ad and im sure the app id and ad id are correct.

What's wrong with this code?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;


public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string appId = "ca-app-pub-7564160460291568~xxxxxxxx";

    private BannerView bannerAd;

void Start()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
    RequestBanner();        
}

void RequestBanner()
{
    string bannerId = "ca-app-pub-7564160460291568/xxxxxxx";
    bannerAd = new BannerView(bannerId, AdSize.SmartBanner, 
    AdPosition.Bottom);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    bannerAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
    DisplayBanner();

}

public void DisplayBanner()
{
    bannerAd.Show();
}
```

Comment: ads didn't load ?

Comment: I don't know, nothing shows up.

Comment: you connect  payment method ?

Comment: you cant use real ID without payment method

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1714397?hl=en

Comment: Yes, I added it

Comment: wait 30 minutes

Comment: +-
and try again

Comment: Everything is fine if your test ads work. Real ads will show after changing to real app ids and publishing the app.